# How To Subscribe HTTP get method In Another HTTP get Method Subscription in Angular?

Tags: angular

In Angular, I have a situation to update the data in the parent subscription from the child subscription. Below is the sample code for your reference. Could you please help me to solve it?

```js
 this.httpClientService.get('access/Details?Id=' + Id + '')
        .subscribe((data: Any[]) => {           
            data.forEach((dt, i) => {
              dt.resource.forEach((rr, j) => {
                if (rr.approval.empId != null) {
                  this.httpClientService.get('employee/get?id=' + rr.approval.empId + '')
                  .subscribe((e: Employee) => {
                      data[i].resourceRoles[j].approval.Name = e.lastName + "," + e.firstName;
                    })
                  }
              })
            })          
          })
```

Data is updated after all the action was done. Not able to update in the loop.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You are running an asynchronous operation, so you need to wait for all requests to be completed before you can consume the modified data. You can utilize `EventEmitter` to notify the main process about the completion of all requests.

```js
import { Component, OnInit, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  // ...

})
export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  // ...
  modifiedData: any[];
  notifier = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor(
    // ...
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.notifier.subscribe((value) => {
      // all data items have been modified, do what you want

    });
  }

  // your data retrieval function
  getData() {
    this.httpClientService
    .get('access/Details?Id=' + Id + '')
    .subscribe((data: any[]) => { 
      let requestQty = 0;
      let completedRequestQty = 0;
      this.modifiedData = data.slice(); // make a copy of the data
    
      data.forEach((dt, i) => {

        dt.resource.forEach((rr, j) => {

          if (rr.approval.empId != null) {
            requestQty++; // increment number of requests

            this.httpClientService
            .get('employee/get?id=' + rr.approval.empId + '')
            .subscribe((e: Employee) => {

              this.modifiedData[i].resourceRoles[j].approval.Name = e.lastName + "," + e.firstName;
              completedRequestQty++; // increment number of completed requests

              if (requestQty === completedRequestQty) { // all requests have been completed
                this.notifier.emit(true);
              }
            })
          }

        })

      })
      
      // if no request
      if (requestQty === 0) { 
        this.notifier.emit(true);
      }
          
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Great!! It is working for me. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Sudhakar if it's working, please accept the answer.

Comment: Note that `subscribe` inside `subscribe` is an anti pattern in RxJS.